# Twitter and Facebook buttons show different heights on iPhone Retina Display

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter, facebook-like, retina-display

I'm afraid this could have not any solution, but maybe I'm implementing the buttons wrong.

The problem is that they show like this on iPhone Retina Display. Is there any solution to make them the same height?

[image: Buttons on iPhone 4S Retina Display]

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are not meant to be the same height. You can try to change the height via CSS but it may not work since the button code is most likely injecting a iframe onto your page. Changing the CSS will let you change the size of the buttons, but it may not look pretty since graphics may be stretched.

Comment: The buttons are the same height on "non-retina" displays. I doubt I can change the buttons CSS, I guess there's no other solution than Facebook fixing the code on their end.